# Pass IEnumerable collection to controller using JQuery in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, collections

I want to pass an `IEnumerable` collection from view to controller using JQuery from view to controller in MVC3.

I have a page which takes `IEnumerable` Collection of `Person` model. After adding/modifying person collection using JQuery, I want to update the entire person collection by passing the collection to controller. I tried to pass the collection by constructing a array object in Jquery, but it did not work.

How can I pass the collection to controller?

It can be any collection, its not that only IEnumerable Collection.

It's really urgent.

Comment: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: pass an IEnumerable collection from view to controller by postback or jquery ajax? and u r trying to insert new record also. can u show model view and method code?

Comment: i can help u. updateing collection is easy, but inserting new record alone i need to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to have the names of the controls on the view to have the index of the collection like

```
<input type='text' name='collection[0].Name' />
<input type='text' name='collection[0].Age' />
<input type='text' name='collection[1].Name' />
<input type='text' name='collection[1].Age' />
```

Check this post of Phil Haack about this
[Binding to a List](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)